# Is "more importantly" good English?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

I was taught in school in the UK  that it was either "more important" or "importantly," never "more importantly." We say "interestingly" or "more interesting," not "more interestingly".

Is "**more importantly**" good English?

Comment: This is my preference. Similarly, "firstly" should generally be "first," etc.

Comment: There's already the silly argument about *first* vs. *firstly* (already mentioned by Cactus above). Both are correct and acceptable, and mean subtly/significantly different things, depending on whether the immediate or the ultimate semantic interests us.

Comment: @CactusHouse http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/firstly

Comment: How does one support 'This is my preference' evolving so rapidly into 'similarly one _should_'? Pragmatic markers don't have to look adjectives. In fact, they usually look just like adverbs (and so often get dumped in the same classification dustbin). 'Frank, I'd speak with your boss' isn't the same as 'Frankly, I'd speak with your boss'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Likewise, 'Sure, I'd speak with your boss' is not the same as 'Shirley, I'd speak with your boss'

Answer (score 8):

**Comparing** levels of *importance* and *interest* seems normal on its face. I assume Paul Brians earned his stripes to become Emeritus Professor of English Washington State University, but it seems [his prescriptive opinion](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/importantly.html) about leading with a sentence adverb has been overruled by *Everyman*:

> When speakers are trying to impress audiences with their rhetoric,
>   they often seem to feel that the extra syllable in “importantly” lends
>   weight to their remarks: “and more importantly, I have an abiding love
>   for the American people.” However, these pompous speakers are wrong.
>   It is rarely correct to use this form of the phrase because it is
>   seldom adverbial in intention. Say “more important” instead. The same
>   applies to “most importantly”; it should be “most important.”

There may be certain situations where combining the comparative adverb [*more*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/more?q=More#more) with the adverb *importantly* does not make sense, but that prohibition generally defies grammatical definition. As an *[adverb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb)*, *more* is an extremely flexible modifier:

> a word that modifies a verb, adjective, other adverb, determiner, noun
>   phrase, clause, or sentence...
>
> Adverbs are traditionally regarded as one of the parts of speech.
>   However, modern linguists note that it has come to be used as a kind
>   of "catch-all" category, used to classify words with various different
>   types of syntactic behavior, not necessarily having much in common
>   except that they do not fit into any of the other available categories
>   (noun, adjective, preposition, etc.)

The prohibition also flies in the face of conventional usage:

See the usage graph for [more importantly.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20importantly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20importantly%3B%2Cc0)

A similar graph appears for [more interestingly.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more%20interestingly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmore%20interestingly%3B%2Cc0)

It seems that this prohibition was enforced until the 1940's when *more importantly* started to break out of the prescriptive box. By the turn of the millennium, *more interestingly* was 8 times more popular than in 1940. *More importantly* was 35 times more popular. *More interestingly* still seems a bit awkward, but *more importantly* is ubiquitous 15 years later.

*More important/interesting* works in some situations. *More importantly/interestingly* works in other situations. Leading with a [*sentence adverb*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sentence-adverb) was once considered pompous, but the expression has scored a reversal, and the prohibition is now pure pretension.

---

public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/importantly.html

www.oxforddictionaries.com

en.wikipedia.org

Comment: I wouldnt say 'conventional', maybe 'popular' usage or to address this question 'more popularly' heard these days.

Comment: -1 They are not comparable. I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: Here is a question to consider, @RaghuramanR, what **duration** of popularity and **extent** of saturation transforms a popular usage from *expression du jour* into *expression de jure*.

Comment: With all due respect to your well earned reputation, @Kris, it seems they are comparable in this matter of an **arbitrary prohibition** against popular usage, which was the OP's question. I offered no other comparison.

Comment: @ScotM 'duration' of popularity and 'extent' of saturation of a word AS WRITTEN is depicted by the 'popular' Google Ngram viewer!  If we compare popular with popularly and more popularly, we do see how these words are (not) in vogue.

Comment: That wrestling image in your conclusion surely expresses the dynamic between prescriptive grammar and descriptive grammar.

Answer (score 3):

I think the origin of the prohibition against *"more importantly"* may be that when it comes at the beginning of sentences, *importantly* is not used as a sentence adverb. The reasoning is that if it's not grammatical, putting *more* in front of it shouldn't make it grammatical.  People don't say

> Importantly, we need to figure out how to pay the rent.

So the idea was that if we can't start a sentence with *"Importantly"*, we shouldn't be able to start one with *"More importantly"*. We should use *"More important"* because it's an ellipsis for a phrase like *"What is more important ..."*.

Since we can use *"Interestingly"* at the beginning of a sentence, we should be able to use *"More interestingly"*. On the other hand, since we can also use *"What is more interesting ..."*, there's nothing ungrammatical about starting a sentence with *"More interesting"*.

Nobody should ever have objected to *"more importantly"* in sentences like:

> This issue, bearing so importantly on our economy and even more importantly on our system of education, ...

So what do I think?

There is a good argument that as a sentence adverb, *more importantly* is ungrammatical, and indeed [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=More+important%2C+More+importantly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMore%20important%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMore%20importantly%3B%2Cc0) shows it wasn't used in the 19th century.

The same argument says that *more interestingly* is indeed grammatical. (Unless you want to say that *interestingly* is not a valid sentence adverb; it wasn't in the 19th century, but it is now. See these [two](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=More+interesting%2CMore+interestingly%2CInterestingly&year_start=1800&year_end=1960&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMore%20interesting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMore%20interestingly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CInterestingly%3B%2Cc0) [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=More+interesting%2CMore+interestingly+&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMore%20interesting%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMore%20interestingly%3B%2Cc0)).

However, the usage of *more importantly* is already well-established, so any crusade against it is a losing cause.